# React native - disable scrolling in 1 direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to disable one ScrollView in react native (iOS)?

I mean i need only to pull down to refresh but, I can also pull up.
I want to disable the pull up.

```
  <ScrollView

                        refreshControl={
                            <RefreshControl
                                refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
                                onRefresh={this._onRefresh}></RefreshControl>}
                        style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any prop in scrollview that would do just that.

One way to do it I can think of is to create a state that keeps track of if you are scrolling up or not. And then calculate which way you are scrolling by doing something like this:

```js
const [scrollDisabled, setScrollDisabled] = useState(false);

let viewPosition = 0;

const disableDownwardScroll = event => {
    const currentPosition = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const isScrollingDown =
            currentPosition > 0 && 
            currentPosition > viewPosition
                ? true
                : false;
    setScrollDisabled(isScrollingDown);
}


return(
    <ScrollView 
        onScroll={disableDownwardScroll} 
        disableScrollViewPanResponder={scrollDisabled}>

        <Content />

    </ScrollView>
);
```

I have myself never used the prop "disableScrollViewPanResponder" before, but I think it's something along the lines of this is what you need.